# Connect OutlookMail Fail A1 and A3 Errors JavaMail with simple login and pass to connect in Outlook365 Mail

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

i need connect in outlook365 just to read email , with login and pass to one integration, and i need to be login and pass without XOAUTH.

I already tried a lot of codes without success, if anyone can help i will be grateful.
Follow my code Java 17

===========

UPDATE 19/11/2023
from @MAX
its is impossible.

So anyone, use another mail box, with login and pass programaticaly to login  ? And that works still in java ?

can i made a rule inside main email to foward to another one. And this new "email" in "new plataform" i can access programatically.

ex/. email received in outlook , automatic redirect, to yahoo , in yahoo i will get this email. and use.

(i tried yahoo, but the flow to create thirdy party access is disable for now)

```
MailConnector.java

package br.com.myproject.utils;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class MailConnector {

    static String user = "myEmailFromCompanyOffice365Enterprise";
    static String senha = "password";
    
    
    public  static void connect() throws Exception {
        
    
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "mypackage.utils.ExchangeSSLSocketFactory");
        prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "mypackage.utils.ExchangeSSLSocketFactory");
        prop.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        prop.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
      
          //prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
          //Add this line ERROR A3 ,  remove this line ERROR A1

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");

        store.connect("outlook.office365.com", user, senha);

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        System.out.println("Total Message:" + folder.getMessageCount());
        System.out.println("Unread Message:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

        Message messages[] = folder.getMessages();

        for (Message mail : messages) {

            System.out.println("*********************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");

            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());
            System.out.println("*******************************");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        connect();
    }
     
    
}
```

Reading some problems about that, i add one class to negotiate credentials with microsoft and add in package , and in props session.

This is the class. (i just copy and past this class)

```
ExchangeSSLSocketFactory.java

package br.com.myproject.utils;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class ExchangeSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
private SocketFactory socketFactory;

public ExchangeSSLSocketFactory() {
    try {
        socketFactory = SocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EmptyTrustManager() }, null);
        sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)context.getSocketFactory();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private final class EmptyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) throws CertificateException {}

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) throws CertificateException {}

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
    }
}

public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
    return new ExchangeSSLSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean flag) throws IOException {
    return sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, s, i, flag);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i, InetAddress inaddr1, int j) throws IOException {
    return socketFactory.createSocket(inaddr, i, inaddr1, j);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i) throws IOException {
    return socketFactory.createSocket(inaddr, i);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inaddr, int j) throws IOException {
    return socketFactory.createSocket(s, i, inaddr, j);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String s, int i) throws IOException {
    return socketFactory.createSocket(s, i);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return socketFactory.createSocket();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

}
```

If anyone have a solution or understand better about protocols and what i need to do to make the integration works, will be amazing. This solution cannot provide XOAUTH, need to be login and pass. Reading the forum i found lot of people with solutions working but not share the code =/

Comment: You _cannot_ log in with a password.  Period.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online : `Basic authentication is now disabled in all tenants. Before December 31 2022, you could re-enable the affected protocols if users and apps in your tenant couldn't connect. Now no one (you or Microsoft support) can re-enable Basic authentication in your tenant.`

Comment: You may be able to use certificate based authentication (which is not a password; I don't know if O365 in the cloud supports this, this is something you will have to specifically setup on the server side), or OAUTH.  Though note, OAUTH supports things like service accounts, etc., if the "logging in with a web browser" part is what styiming you

Comment: Any Free Mail Box Still is able to login with email and pass ? i can redirect email to there and login programatically there.

Comment: I believe consumer microsoft accounts (eg hotmail/outlook.com) can still login with a password, but you'll have to do your own research there.  Or, stand up your own SMTP server!  Push is better than pull!